# Ubercart Orders to Display in Calendar

Tags: drupal, calendar, view, ubercart

I am building a booking system with Drupal and Ubercart. The booking system is for a paintball site, so I have 200 places I can sell per day, of varied packages including different amounts of paintballs.

I currently have products set as packages that people can purchase, and pay through ubercart on the site. This all works fine as far as selecting and buying a package....

Next, I want to add a calendar to the admin section of the site, so our booking office can log in and see which dates people are booking the games on.

This would mean the customer needs to enter a date during checkout, and then something like Views could find the date, and show it on the calendar once the booking is completed. Therefore giving the booking office a full list of booked games.

I have installed the calendar module, that works beautifully with views, and I can create calendars easily. The only bit I am struggling on, is how to add a date field into Ubercart  checkout, in a way that views & calendar can detect it.

I have added uc extra field and uc addressess, which allows me to add an extra field into the billing address section. So i've done that for now, but the field is just a text field, when Ideally i would like it to be a jquery pop up menu.

I have installed (and uninstalled) multiple Rooms and Uc hotel booking modules, as they just do not meet my needs, and seem to make it overly complicated. Plus once they are installed, they would need hacking to only accept a single game date, and not a booking, or rooms, or children, pets etc.

Has anyone built a system like this before? Or could you point me in the right direction?

Currently using these modules on this project...
-ubercart
-rules
-token
-views
-ctools
-entity api
-date
-stringoverride
-calendar
-uc address field
-uc field attribute
-uc extra fields pane

Also, if it helps, take a look at the progress here... booking.webfroth.co.uk

Comment: Sorry I can't give an answer, this is because there is no simple answer to your needs. I think you better start from Drupal Commerce, and maybe from the Rooms distribution, but you will have lots of work in order to make it the way you want it. As a developer who made similar things, I will be happy to help in specific questions when they arrise. Good luck,

Comment: I have used webform to add the date popup into the checkout page, and then im using the webform views integration module to read suibmission data into views. I am able to add submission data now, but I am struggling with getting a calendar to organise itself into "game date" submissions. I'll keep trying and let you know how i get on!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try - 
[Agreservations](https://drupal.org/project/agreservations)
The agreservations-module is a module to handle reservations of resources.

Comment: Yes I did try that module, but it wasn't what I was looking for. In the end I used the webform-Uc moodule to create a webform as a product, which I could then get all the information i required, and display it in a view using a webform submission relationship. It still isnt what we were looking for, but its working for the time being.